# CSS: Filling blank place under the condition of having fixed heights or widths

Tags: css, height, width, fixed

The solution doesn't need to be supported by all browsers.

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="content">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="footer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Let's see. page got `width:100%;height:100%`. header and content got both `width:100%` (is this required anyway?), but they got fixed heights, let's say `height: 200px` and `height: 500px`. Now I want the footer to fill the rest of the page.

Any solution for that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your CSS, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like this:

```
html,body,#page {height:100%}
#page {position:relative;}
#header {height:200px;background:green;}
#content {height:500px;background:grey;}
#footer {position:absolute;top:700px;bottom:0;background:red;width:100%;}
```

in fact you set `position:absolute` for `#footer` and give a value for `top` 700px; the total height of `#header` and `#content` and `bottom:0` so will fill the empty space.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/icuza3/2

Comment: Thanks so much! But your first line caused a vertical scrollbar. So I just removed it.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know css3 can do "Maths" adn simple functions
see [w3c-specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) , search for "calc" ;)